# how to solve this error in codeigniter and mysql?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

[image: img]
am getting data table warning

> DataTables warning: table id={table} - Requested unknown parameter
>   '{parameter}' for row {5},

Comment: please include a [mcve]. see also [ask]

Comment: We need to be able to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: Possible your table head columns and table body columns counts are different

Answer (score 0):

Give your table a ID and the pass that id to the javascript.
Use this in your table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="users">



</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('#users').DataTable( {
    responsive: true
} );
</script>
```